# How can i update a field / post a form without redirecting or reloading a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have the following code to update just one field in my database which a field called `Flag` which is a Boolean field. How can I update `flag` field  without reloading the page and redirecting. I tired ajax/Jquery but it works for the first time then stopped when updating the next item in the `<li>` list, on the next list click it shows ID and Flag value in address bar but not updating record only works when updating the first item in the list.

```
 <form id="updateflag">
         @if (item.Flag == "Off")
           {
            <input name="ID" type="hidden" value="@item.ID" />  //value changes based on the selected list item
            <input name="Flag" type="hidden" value="true" />//value changes based on the selected list item
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">&nbsp; @(Localizer["Turn Flag On"]) // value changes based on the selected list item</button>
            }
           @if (item.Flag == "On")
             {
              <input name="ID" type="hidden" value="@item.ID" />//value changes based on the selected list item
              <input name="Flag" type="hidden" value="false" />//value changes based on the selected list item
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">&nbsp; @(Localizer["Turn Flag Off"])</button>//value changes based on the selected list item
             }
  </form>
```

//the above form ID field changes

I used the following Ajax/Jquery which works once then on the next try it shown me the posted data in the url but not updating the field

```
$('#updateflag').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let Data = $(this).serialize();

    $.post({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Customer/updateFlag",
        data: Data,
        success: window.location.reload()
    })
})
```

what is the best way to update a field value on button click without redirecting and show the updated result instantly?

Comment: Why reload the page when you use AJAX? Return the value in the result and where you have `success: window.location.reload()` which is weird syntax, have `success: function(result) { /* update your field here */ }`

Comment: You mean you have a lot of forms which id is updateflag? If you have multiple form that the jquery click binding will just work for the first one. You could try to set a class for all the forms and use class selector in the jquery like this: `<form id="updateflag" class="update">`, jquery: `$('.update').submit`.

Comment: @BrandoZhang yep you absolutely right, that fixes it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your jquery codes, I found you just bind the click event for the updateflag.

If you have multiple form that the Jquery click binding will just work for the first one.

You could try to set a class for all the forms and use class selector in the jquery like this: `<form id="updateflag" class="update">`, jquery: `$('.update').submit`.

Comment: yes, thank you but is there anyway to not reload the whole page just reflect the change

Comment: Your success method has fired window.location.reload method. Could you please tell me why you call this method?

Comment: without window.location.reload i can see the updated value. it update the field in the  database but doesn't reflect in the view that's why i added window.location.reload, in my view i want to see the updated value. I used label as `<div class="quarter">
                                            <div id="Flag"> <label> Flag</label><br /> @customer.Flag</div>
                                        </div>`